# Failure of election for next session

Tags: staking, validator, session, election

Just a clarification, suppose that the `pallet_session::rotate_session` is not able to retrieve the next validation set due to an election failure inside the `pallet_staking::new_session` function.
Is then the current validation set re-used to solve the problem of missing validators?
Is it possible also that such failure arise when the `election_multi_phase` pallet doesn’t complete an offline election process?

Answer (score 1):

> Is then the current validation set re-used to solve the problem of missing validators?

Correct.

> Is it possible also that such failure arise when the election_multi_phase pallet doesn’t complete an offline election process?

Yes, and in fact, if `type ElectionProvider` of `pallet_staking::Config` is set to an instance of `election_multi_phase`, then it is `election_multi_phase` that is first failing, possible in the offline election process, then staking is notified, and the same failure is finally passed down to `pallet_sesion` on `new_session` .

Comment: thanks, very helpful